# Which software/framework to use to create App for Call Calibration for Quality Dept

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. If not, please direct me to the right place.

We used to have an application that was created using VB and Microsoft Access. It was an application to score calls from Agents and would then run a few calculations and grade those agents based on a few algorithms.

We replicated all that Access data onto SQL but for some reason, we were just not able to connect the VB application to the SQL Database instead. The application was also outdated and we needed a change.

Can anyone suggest software/framework that can be used to create a new application with an ability to connect to a SQL database?

EDIT: We have a Microsoft Office 365 subscription. I was thinking of using PowerApps. I've never used it before. Does anyone think this could help serve my purpose?

Comment: Determine where the application will be hosted.  Use something they support.

Answer (score 1):

I have extensive experience of using PowerApps to create applications connected to SQL Server (in my case Azure SQL Database), and am mostly satisfied.
There are some constraints, but not major.  Please see [these posts](https://baizini-it.com/blog/index.php/tag/azure-sql-database/) for some further information.
I would suggest PowerApps if you have Office365.